# How do I loop over each line inside a file with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am looking for something that would be similar to `with_items:` but that would get the list of items from a file instead of having to include it in the playbook file.

How can I do this in ansible?

Comment: why don't you create a variable for your list of items(in a separate file) and use the variable in `with_items` ?

Comment: I stated clearly that I need a text file, with one item per  line. This file is generated outside so that's *why* I need it.

Comment: i've removed my answer, a small misunderstanding

Comment: first: `shell: cat file; register: res`, next `with_items: res.stdout_lines`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I managed to find an easy alternative:

```
- debug: msg="{{item}}"
  with_lines: cat files/branches.txt
```

Comment: This will not work when you execute a command remotely: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-the-results-of-a-program-execution

Comment: So you have to upload the **branches.txt** to the server then use it

Comment: Use: `with_items: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/branches.txt').splitlines() }}"` for using local file.

Answer (score 41):

Latest Ansible [recommends `loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) instead of `with_something`. It can be used in combination with `lookup` and `splitlines()`, as [Ikar Pohorský](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541870/how-do-i-loop-over-each-line-inside-a-file-with-ansible#comment96524289_33544101) pointed out:

```
- debug: msg="{{item}}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/branches.txt').splitlines() }}"
```

`files/branches.txt` should be relative to the playbook

Answer (score 14):

Lets say you have a file like

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

And you want to install these items. Simply get the file contents to a variable using register. And use this variable for `with_items`. Make sure your file has one item per line.

```
---
- hosts: your-host
  remote_user: your-remote_user
  tasks:
  - name: get the file contents
    command: cat /path/to/your/file
    register: my_items
  - name: install these items
    pip: name:{{item}}
    with_items: my_items.stdout_lines
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work. Still, I was able to find another easier approach already: `with_lines`

Answer (score 9):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned the ansible [**Lookups**](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents), I think that is exactly what you want.

It reads contents that **you want to use in your playbook but do not want to include inside the playbook** from **files, pipe**, **csv**, **redis** etc from **your local control machine**(not from remote machine, that is important, since in most cases, these contents are alongside your playbook on your local machine), and it works with ansible loops.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Loop over lines in a file
      debug:
        var: item
      with_lines: cat "./files/lines"
```

`with_lines` here is actually loop with lines lookup, to see how the `lines` lookup works, see the code [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/lines.py#L32), it just runs any commands you give it(so you can give it any thing like echo, cat etc), then **split** the output into lines and return them.

There are many powerful lookups, to get the comprehensive list, check out the [lookup plugins folder](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup).

Comment: This will not work when you execute a command remotely: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-the-results-of-a-program-execution

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Read files from the local machine, loop over the lines and execute a task remotely.

Comment: nice answer. But i have one more improvisation question for this. can we do some operation like "cut" based on delimiter to the line extracted from the file before using it?