# Need to iterate over file containing hostname and use that value within the task

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a code which will use nagios module of ansible to put downtime for hostnames defined in the file. My query is how can I write code to iterate over file containing hosts. My objective is to use this task

```
  tasks:
    - nagios:
        author: ansible
        action: downtime
        minutes: 30
        service: all
        host: **{{variable value from the file containing hostnames}} ## here is what I want the loop variable should be able to put the hostname extracted from file**
        comment: Downtime scheduled deled by Ansible
        cmdfile: /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [How do I loop over each line inside a file with ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541870/how-do-i-loop-over-each-line-inside-a-file-with-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to loop **with_lines**. See example below

```
    - debug: var=item                                                                        
      with_lines: cat /scratch/tmp/test
```

Comment: will it take cat /scratch/tmp/test the unix command over here

Comment: Generally, [with_lines](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/lines.html) "split the output (of any command) into lines, returning them as a list".