# How to create directory using ansible with directory names taken from a file

Tags: ansible

How to create a directory using ansible where directory names should be taken from a different file

I have tried using with_file command which didnt help much

```
-bash-4.2$ cat main.yml
---
- name: It is a test yml
  file:
    dest: "/tmp/destination/{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_file:
    - "/tmp/stuff.yml"

-bash-4.2$ cat /tmp/stuff.yml
test
hello
world
```

The expected output is - 3 Folders to be created as below

```
/tmp/destination/test
/tmp/destination/hello
/tmp/destination/world
```

But the output what I received is - Only 1 Folder created as below

```
/tmp/destination/test?hello?world
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541870/how-do-i-loop-over-each-line-inside-a-file-with-ansible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [with_lines](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/lines.html#lines-read-lines-from-command)

```
- name: It is a test yml
  file:
    dest: "/tmp/destination/{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_lines: cat /tmp/stuff.yml
```